# jQuery ListBox single or multiple selected item(s)

Tags: jquery

I got an ASP.NET ListBox, and on change I need to display the (single or multiple) selected text(s) in (single or multiple) alert(s). The number of alerts should be equal to the number of items selected. I tried the following code, where I am getting an extra alert showing the first item in the ListBox. Where did I go wrong?

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="100px"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">White</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="2"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4"> Khaki </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListBox1 ").change(function () {
        $("option").each(function () { 
            if (this.selected) {
                alert(this.text);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems working well, http://jsfiddle.net/9zthu/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that your asp code is rendering the listitems as this in HTML:

```
...
<option value="1" selected="true">
<option value="2" selected="false">
...
```

Since the attribute "selected" is present in both cases, checking this.selected will return true if the attribute is set to true or false because "selected" exists either way.

An easier way to accomplish the same objective is to replace this:

```
$("#ListBox1 ").change(function () {
    $("option").each(function () { 
        if (this.selected) {
            alert(this.text);
        }
    });
});
```

with this:

```
$('#ListBox1').find('option:selected').map(function () {
  alert.log($(this).text());
});
```